# UWP App for Windows 10 crashing on Phone but working on PC

Tags: c#, exception, crash, windows-10, uwp

I am making an UWP app for Windows 10. The app works fine on PC but it crashes on Phone. I am not sure why it happens. In my app, I am reading through a json file.

```
var lines = File.ReadAllLines("Assets/xxxxxx.json");
```

After it runs the above line, it goes to App.g.i.cs file and runs the below code.

```
#if DEBUG && !DISABLE_XAML_GENERATED_BREAK_ON_UNHANDLED_EXCEPTION
        UnhandledException += (sender, e) =>
        {
            if (global::System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached) global::System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
        };
#endif
```

And then it crashes and comes out of the app.

I have also added the Reference to Windows 10 Mobile from Solution Explorer.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Check out what error message it shows. Hover over e to get it when the exception occurs.

Comment: @AbsoluteSith That's the thing. It doesn't show any error message. I used break point to find out the problem. There I found out that control goes to App.g.i.cs file and crashes from there.

Comment: You should try to find the exact location where crash occurs with breakpoints.

Comment: use `try{ } catch{ }` to catch the error if any

Comment: if you put a breakpoint in the UnhandledException handler (or put a try/catch block around it as Kishor suggested) you should be able to look in the exception variable to see what Message it is sending you for the exception.

Comment: I got the exception "Exception thrown: 'System.TypeLoadException' in System.IO.FileSystem.DLL"

Comment: What's the windows version you are running on the desktop and your phone ? And what are the min and target SDKs that you have set for your app?

Comment: Could you share a [mcve]? With the one line code, I can't reproduce your issue in my side. It works well both on desktop and on my phone.

Comment: @karann I am running build 10586.420 on my PC and build 14379 on my phone. Min SDK is 10240. Target is 14371.